# Jupyter notebook pip install scispacy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am using Jupyter Notebooks and have been trying to install scispacy (https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/).
Following the instructions I think I have installed scispacy using

```
!pip install scispacy
```

But cannot install the actual package I want en_core_sci_sm (https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.4.0/en_core_sci_sm-0.4.0.tar.gz). The instructions say to use:

```
!pip install <download url>
```

but this returns the error: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Is this in python 2 or 3?

Comment: Do you have more output than "The syntax of the command is incorrect"?  Please show us.

Comment: Python 3 and no, that is the only output

Answer (score 0):

try to download the tar.gz first and replace  with path to the tar.gz

Comment: This didn't work, gave me a really long error message. Do you want me to post it all?